# Is the Euler function $\phi$ constant in arbitrarily large intervals?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, totient-function, arithmetic-functions

> Is it true that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a natural number $x$ such that $\phi(x)=\phi(x+1)=\cdots=\phi(x+k)$, where $\phi$ is the Euler's totient function?

I thought about this problem today and I've no idea how to solve it or even attack it.

Also, I would be interested in variants of this problem, in which we substitue $\phi$ for another number-theoretical interesting functions, like $\sigma,\tau,\lambda$, etc.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume you mean $k$ consecutive naturals?

Comment: For what it's worth:  to the best of my knowledge this is unknown.  Looks hard.  Mathworld tells us that the only 3 consecutive integers under $10^{10}$ with the same totient value are 5186,5187,5188.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html

Comment: @Nitin  Oh, I assumed the OP wanted consecutive values.  Upon rereading, I see that isn't stated.  Might make it a lot easier if you drop that...

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question. I meant consecutive naturals.

Comment: No problem.  The other question might be interesting too, and looks a lot more tractable.  But I still don't know how to do it.

Comment: For the consecutive integers one, there's a good chance it is false. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Ratio_of_consecutive_values.

Comment: @Nitin: I'm not sure how much those results bear on the present question? Certainly we'd expect $\phi$ to vary a lot, and those results quantify that, but they don't make it seem yet less likely to me that such $x$ might exist for all $k$ than it already did anyway.

Comment: Erdös conjectured in 1945 that the answer is yes: see http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1945-51-08/S0002-9904-1945-08390-6/ 
DOI: http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1945-08390-6

Comment: Very hard question... I tend to think that is false from the definition of totient $\varphi(n) =n \prod_{p\mid n} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$.