# Infinite number of primes of the form $2^x \cdot 3^y + 1$?

Tags: number-theory

Are there an infinite number of primes of the form $2^x \cdot 3^y + 1$?

I really have no idea where to start with this.  I thought of it because it would imply an affirmative answer to this recent question: [Does Euler's $\phi$ function have the same value in arbitrarily large subsets of $\mathbb{N}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1355776/does-eulers-phi-function-have-the-same-value-in-arbitrarily-large-subsets-of).

Comment: It seems likely to be unknown - such questions are rarely known.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A005109

Comment: Seems to be an open problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierpont_prime

Comment: Such questions are rarely known, but almost always it's obviously "yes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Guy's Unsolved Problems](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387208602) number A18. This doesn't necessarily mean that it's not doable, but I do think it's not currently been done. [I think it is not currently doable, however].